# How can I upload to Amazon S3 after authenticating a user via Parse Cloud Code?

Tags: parse-platform, amazon-s3

Scenario:  A _User is registered on my site.  I want to allow them to upload pictures but ONLY if they are logged in.  To verify their session, I would be using Parse cloud code.  However how do I implement the actual file upload?

Would I -

1. Pass the file through the cloud code to Amazon S3? In this case the Cloud Code has a master key to Amazon S3 and the cloud code would just pass the file through. (is this possible?).
2. Verify user identity with Cloud Code.  Grab a temporary token for the user/client to upload directly to Amazon S3 themselves (however this requires an additional call on upload completion to update the database).

I'm just using the Parse Javascript SDK on the frontend and Cloud Code at the moment.  Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

In the cloud, `request.user` will give you an auth'd user if there is one.  You can use that as all the authentication you need, or check additional conditions in the cloud (e.g. user belonging to some Role).

I can't think of a good way to pass-through without creating a PFFile (which anyway is just parse's front-end on the S3 that they manage for you).  Comparing resource use between that and returning a temporary access token (just a single extra request), seems to me hands down in favor of idea 2.